# Installing jsonwebtoken to latest react version causing webpack < 5 use to include polyfills for node js core modules by default

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm having this issue when I started to install jsonwebtoken on the frontend side(react js). I'm using the latest version of react.
Error
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Thanks